# EXT-JS combo-box's store reset after expand when data is loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I want to dynamically add items to a combo box item.
This is how its defined:

```
{
      xtype: 'combobox',
      id: 'tierTypeCB',
      fieldLabel: 'Tiers\' type',
      labelWidth: 70,
      editable: false,
      valueField: 'type',
      displayField: 'type',
      store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
          fields: ['type'],
          data: []
      })
}
```

In other part of the code, I have this function which is supposed to add the items:

```
onGetTiersSuccess: function(response) { // this is a 'success' function of an AJAX request
    var decodedResponse = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    var tierTypeCB =  Ext.getCmp('tierTypeCB');
    var tierTypesStore = tierTypeCB.getStore();
    for (var tierType in decodedResponse){
        tierTypesStore .add({type: tierType});
    }
}
```

The thing is that when the drop-down is opened its empty.  what i've found out, is that my code puts the data into the combo-box's store, but once the combo is expanded the store is emptied.
I've done some more testing using chrome's console.  I commented-out the 'onGetTiersSuccess' function.  Instead I just type into the console `Ext.getCmp('tierTypeCB').getStore().add({type: 'abc'})`
If I open the combo-box its empty.  However, if I **first** open the combo-box (before adding that item), and only then add the item, once I open the combo-box again I can see there the item I've added.
It seems that adding item to the combo-box before opening it, 'resets' the combo-box's store once its opened.
I've tried to by-pass it by calling `Ext.getCmp('tierTypeCB').expand()` and then calling `Ext.getCmp('tierTypeCB').collapse()` before adding the items, but that didn't help.
i've also tried not setting the combo-box's store where i define it, but create a store object and then bind it to the combo-box (using the `bindStore()` command) and that didn't help either.

At this point I'm clueless, so I'd appreciate it if you have any idea that might help me.

Thanks,
eRez

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `queryMode` property to `local`. What is happening is the empty store isn't being created until you try to expand the combobox. The `queryMode` property is, by default, `remote`. Setting it to `local` should fix the issue because it will load the store when the combobox is created.

Comment: BINGO!!!!!!!!!!
added all the extra !'s for there's a minimum length for a comment :-)

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use the `lastQuery` config of the combo to keep the store from reloading when first expanded.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    lastQuery: '',
    id: 'tierTypeCB',
    fieldLabel: 'Tiers\' type',
    labelWidth: 70,
    editable: false,
    valueField: 'type',
    displayField: 'type',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
        fields: ['type'],
        data: []
    })
}
```

See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-property-lastQuery

Comment: +1 this worked for me, while queryMode: 'local' still loaded, ty